# Delphi: Offset of record field

Tags: delphi, record, offset

I'm looking for ways to obtain the offset of a field in a Delphi record. These 2 following methods work but i was hoping for a cleaner way. Basically i would have liked the third showmessage to work. Any ideas?

```
type
 rec_a=record
  a:longint;
  b:byte;
  c:pointer;
 end;

{$warnings off}
function get_ofs1:longint;
var
 abc:^rec_a;
begin
 result:=longint(@abc.c)-longint(abc);
end;
{$warnings on}

function get_ofs2:longint;
asm
 mov eax,offset rec_a.c
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs1));
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs2));
// showmessage(inttostr(longint(addr(rec_a.c)))); // is there a way to make this one work?
end;
```

edit:
 Alright, the below answer works fine, thanks! For reference, here's the assembler output for the various options:

```
---- result:=longint(@abc.c)-longint(abc); ----
lea edx,[eax+$08]
sub edx,eax
mov eax,edx

---- mov eax,offset rec_a.c ----
mov eax,$00000008

---- result:=longint(@rec_a(nil^).c); ----
xor eax,eax
add eax,$08
```

edit2: looks like this is a duplicate of a previous question: [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168959/get-position-of-a-struct-var) as noted below by RRUZ. As shown there, another method is to declare a global variable and use it as follows. Strangely enough the compiler still isnt able to assign the proper value at compile time as is seen in the assembler output, so for both efficiency and readability it`s better to use the nil method.

```
---- var ----
----  rec_a_ofs:rec_a; ----
---- ... ----
---- result:=longint(@rec_a_ofs.c)-longint(@rec_a_ofs); ----
mov eax,$0045f5d8
sub eax,$0045f5d0
```

edit3: Ok revised code with all know ways to accomplish this. Note that the assembler code generated for the 3rd, 4th, and 5th (class method) ways is identical, whether they are inlined or not. Choose your favorite way when you get to do this stuff!

```
type
 prec_a=^rec_a;
 rec_a=record
  a:longint;
  b:byte;
  c:pointer;

  class function offset_c:longint;static;inline;
 end;

//const
// rec_a_field_c_offset=longint(@rec_a(nil^).c); // no known way to make this work

{$warnings off}
function get_ofs1:longint;inline;
var
 abc:^rec_a;
begin
 result:=longint(@abc.c)-longint(abc);
end;
{$warnings on}

function get_ofs2:longint;
asm
 mov eax,offset rec_a.c
end;

function get_ofs3:longint;inline;
begin
 result:=longint(@rec_a(nil^).c);
end;

function get_ofs4:longint;inline;
begin
 result:=longint(@prec_a(nil).c);
end;

class function rec_a.offset_c:longint;
begin
 result:=longint(@prec_a(nil).c);
end;

var
 rec_a_ofs:rec_a;

function get_ofs6:longint;inline;
begin
 result:=longint(@rec_a_ofs.c)-longint(@rec_a_ofs);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs1));
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs2));
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs3));
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs4));
 showmessage(inttostr(rec_a.offset_c));
 showmessage(inttostr(get_ofs6));
// showmessage(inttostr(rec_a_field_c_offset));
end;
```

Comment: `offset` keyword is not needed in BASM code; just `mov eax, rec_a.c`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Position of a struct var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168959/get-position-of-a-struct-var)

Comment: @serg even redundant code may add soem safety - killing the ambiguity where u didn't expected it or making syntax error where u mistyped and more relaxed coding would be compilable with wrong results

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I always use this approach:

```
Offset := Integer(@rec_a(nil^).c);
```

Don't let the use of `nil^` put you off, it's perfectly safe. And don't worry about 64 bit pointer truncation. If you have a record whose size is >4GB then you have bigger problems!

Comment: Terrific!!! with my ASM background i never thought of that... shame...

Did u tried to make it const ?

Comment: @Arioch I don't think you can make a const expression for a field offset

Comment: Well, at least that can be done in class constructor rather than instance constructor :-)

Comment: I tried it and [const rec_a_field_c_offset=longint(@rec_a(nil^).c);] returns an error saying the result isnt a constant :/

Comment: Marladu, see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13170195/576719) how to introduce a class method in your record. Makes the code look nicer.

Comment: Marladu, and declare the function as `inline` and you will see that the offset is inlined as a const.

Comment: @LURD Although the compiler can evaluate it at compile time, I don't know any way to make a `const` of a field offset. Do you?

Comment: David, declaring the class function as inlined skips the function call and inserts the offset value. It's not a const in a declaration meaning but in a practical meaning.

Comment: @LURD Yes, I know all that. There's utility in being able to declare something as `const`.

Comment: @LU RD: Disregard the comment I left 5 minutes ago (and just deleted), I found your answer and am testing it, I'm still new to the site and a bit slow learner sometimes.

Comment: @LU RD: Ok I tested it and there is no difference between your method and the accepted answer outside of readability preferences. I will update the first post with all the information I currently know regarding this subject in the next 5 minutes.

Comment: The approach using NIL becomes a pain-in-the-ass when compiling under Delphi .NET

Comment: @Alex I tend to disregard that compiler which has long been discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a generic approach:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,TypInfo,RTTI;

function GetFieldOffset( ARecordTypeInfo : PTypeInfo;
                         const ARecordFieldName : String) : Integer;
var
  MyContext: TRttiContext;
  MyField: TRttiField;
begin
  if (ARecordTypeInfo.Kind <> tkRecord) then
    raise Exception.Create('Not a record type');
  for MyField in MyContext.GetType(ARecordTypeInfo).GetFields do
    if MyField.Name = ARecordFieldName then
    begin
      Exit(MyField.Offset);
    end;
  raise Exception.Create('No such field name:'+ARecordFieldName);
end;
```

And call it like this:

```
ShowMessage( IntToString( GetFieldOffset( TypeInfo(rec_a),'c')));
```

---

Not as fast as your other alternatives, but gives a unified generic solution.

---

Looking at your options here for a clean solution, it seems the best is to declare a generic function:

```
function GetFieldOffset( const P : Pointer) : Integer; Inline;
// Example calls :
//   GetFieldOffset( @PMyStruct(nil).MyParameter);
//   GetFieldOffset( @TMyStruct(nil^).MyParameter);
begin
  Result := Integer( P);
end;
```

So even if the call looks awkward, the function name tells you what's going on.
Inlining the call removes the function call overhead, so it will work as a code beautifier.

It is possible to get constant values for a record base and field address:

```
const
  cStruct : MyStruct = ();
  cMyInteger3Offs : Pointer = @cStruct.MyInteger3;
  cMyStructBase   : Pointer = @cStruct;
```

But this will not make code look cleaner.

Comment: This approach also gives up compile-time type checking and IntelliSense support.

Comment: @UliGerhardt, yes that's sometimes the case using rtti. I looked for a  solution where 'c' could be resolved at compile time, but found no easy way.

Comment: Did you find a hard way? I messed with this so much more than I should and still could never find a way to put a record field offset in a constant. Also of note for the method showed in this answer is that it only works for the newer versions of delphi, older versions don't have the unit rtti.

Comment: This new RTTI possibilities was added in Delphi-2010. I also did some research about defining the offset as a constant, but neither rtti nor advanced records seems to be viable. See my update for a summary.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Sadly still no way to fill a constant cleanly, as to get this as an int I would then need to add "var
 cMyInteger3Offs_Int:longint absolute cMyInteger3Offs;" or initialize variables in an initialization section. After checking with the guy who will do support once i`m done with the development it looks like I'll be using the "inlined nil class function" method since it was the one he found most likely to be able to remember and understand. Thanks for the input on this subject everyone!

Comment: Just a quick note, I don't plan on adding it to the top, but there is a known way to get the offset in a non variable constant, but it is extremely terrible to use for many reasons, and that is to use sizeof(sub-record) as in: 'type rec_a_sub1=record a,b:longint end; const ofs_rec_a_c=sizeof(rec_a_sub1);' . It's so awful to maintain that it's not worth using even in the most performance sensitive inner loop for saving 1 asm statement.

Comment: The obvious problem in case of constant declaration example is that the constant will be physically allocated (is given a memory zone), even if the definition was just a `()`. This might be no problem for records of just a couple of bytes but might be awkward for header + big data zone styled structures.