# Can we implement ANSI C's `offsetof` in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, struct

For reference: The `offsetof` macro(!) takes a `struct` data type and a member of the specified struct as arguments and returns an integer offset of the given member relative to the beginning of the struct. See the [detailed overview and references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof).

The logic behind the generic `offsetof` is quite simple and can be reproduced in Delphi with ease <strike>(more or less)</strike> (literally with ease, elimination of predeclared pointer type requirement makes it a basic inline expression, see David Heffernan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787282/205376) and [comment about swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786986/can-we-implement-ansi-cs-offsetof-in-delphi#comment27701712_18787282) reference and dereference operators) as in-place code. However, I see absolutely no way to convert the in-place code solution to the reusable function. Can we actually do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate, [`Delphi: Offset of record field`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14462103/576719).

Comment: This seems to me to be a subtly different question. The asker knows how to write code to achieve the desired effect, but wants to be able to write it in the same neat and tidy way that `offsetof` allows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are correct. Voting to reopen.

Comment: That's a long standing FPC feature request http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=15416

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without a pre-processor or a built-in function, there's no way to do it quite as cleanly as the `offsetof` macro. The way that `offsetof` is able to do it so cleanly is that the pre-processor does the work. In fact some compilers implement it as a built-in, but that's beside the point. Delphi has no pre-processor, and no built-in `offsetof`.

The cleanest solution I know is like this:

```
NativeUInt(@TMyRecord(nil^).MyField)
```

But that is nothing like as clean as

```
offsetof(struct MyStruct, MyField)
```

Comment: Native[U]Int to preserve portability

Comment: @FreeConsulting Well maybe, but I think that you are unlikely to encounter a struct with size > 2GB. And I hope that your code that uses this is going to assign the result to a Native[U]Int!  ;-)  Thanks for the edit, and you corrected my other mistake too.

Comment: @FreeConsulting I swapped around the pointer de-reference so that the code doesn't require the user to define a bespoke PMyRecord just to use this trick. I think this is as clean as it can be done. But it's rather yucky compared to C.

Comment: FWIW: If you have a need for a lot of these constructs you can declare `const p = PMyRecord(nil)` and use it like `Whatever(p^.MyField)`.

Comment: @UliGerhardt that's a tidy as it gets, but should be `NativeUInt(@p.MyField)` shouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcDurdin, no - `p` is a pointer and needs to be dereferenced with `^` to access its fields. `@p` would give its address, a pointer to a pointer to a record.

Comment: @UliGerhardt, `@p.MyField` gets the address of `p.MyField`, not the address of `p`. That's what we want; we don't want to access the values of the fields (which is what the dereference operator `^` does), because we are not pointing to real data, we are pointing to `nil`. Dereferencing `nil` will of course cause an access violation.

Comment: @Marc Not quite. `@p.MyField` is the same as `@p^.MyField`

Comment: @Uli in Delphi the `^` can be omitted when dereferencing a pointer to record

Comment: @David, yes, that's true, but as you don't need the `^` in this instance, why use it? Both versions return the address of `MyField`, not `p`. As @Uli's first example did not include the `@`, it resulted in a dereference of `p` and an access violation. See also my answer below for a full example.

Comment: @David: Yes, unfortunately. :-)

Comment: @Marc, I use it exactly like that without AV. My `Whatever` routine takes an untyped `var` parameter and does some pointer arithmetic inside.

Comment: @Uli, Yes that works, as a `var` parameter is basically just a pointer, so the dereference is then elided by the compiler. But it wouldn't work if you weren't passing it to a function with a `var` parameter. :)

Comment: @Marc De-referencing nil is absolutely fine. See the code in my answer for example. What is not fine is accessing that memory. You can de-reference nil and then take the address which is exactly what you do in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @DavidHeffernan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787282/1836776) and @UliGerhardt's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786986/can-we-implement-ansi-cs-offsetof-in-delphi#comment27706828_18787282), here's what we now use, tested and in use:

```
procedure foo;
type
  TPerson = record
    DOB: TDate;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
  end;
const
  Offset_TPerson: ^TPerson = nil;
begin
  writeln('OffsetOf FirstName = '+IntToStr(NativeUInt(@Offset_TPerson.FirstName)));
end;
```

Comment: The downside is the extra const declaration which is not needed and I personally prefer to avoid such declarations on grounds of clutter.

Comment: @David, IMHO it makes the inline expression more readable (especially if one has multiple occurrences).

Comment: @UliGerhardt Is `@TMyRecord(nil^).MyField` really harder to read than `@Offset_TMyRecord.MyField`? The former has the benefit of having all the information right there and not requiring you to consult something declared elsewhere. I understand that this comes down to taste to a degree, but I suspect that most of the dislike of the former comes down to a subconscious distaste for `nil^`. For instance, Marc objected to the use of `^` on the grounds that nil was being de-referenced. But in fact de-referencing `nil` is perfectly valid, it's what happens after that matters.  tbc

Comment: contd. So Marc prefers a version that does not include `^` out of fear of de-referencing `nil`. But in fact the code in this answer does de-reference `nil`. The expressions `Offset_TPerson.FirstName` and `Offset_TPerson^.FirstName` have identical meaning. The compiler accepts the former as a matter of convenience. Convenience that was added (perhaps accidentally) when the compiler was extended to support Delphi 1 class instance references. In my view, I actually prefer to see `nil^` because it makes it crystal clear what is really going on.

Comment: But fundamentally it all comes down to personal preference, I do agree. Just don't kid yourself that you aren't writing `nil^` because you obfuscated it!  ;-)

Comment: It all comes down to preference. :-)

Comment: @David is correct here, Marc. Delphi implicitly dereferences pointers to structured types (to support classes), so basically you are doing `Offset_TPerson^.FirstName`