# What is the equivalent function for the CONTAINING_RECORD C macro in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pointers, struct, record

The [CONTAINING_RECORD macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542043%28VS.85%29.aspx) in C returns the base address of a structure/record type variable based on the address of a field member within the structure. It is extremely helpful in cases where I can pass only a predefined record pointer to some Windows API function which triggers callbacks.

For example if I have some types like:

```
type
   tInnerRecord = record
      x, y : integer;
   end;
   pInnerRecord = ^tInnerRecord

tOuterRecord = record
   field1 : integer;
   inner : tInnerRecord;
   field2 : integer;
end;
pOuterRecord = ^tOuterRecord;
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
procedure SomeCallback( pIn : pInnerRecord ); stdcall;
var
   Out : pOuterRecord;
begin
   Out := CONTAINING_RECORD(pIn, tOuterRecord, inner);
   Out.field1 := pIn.x + pIn.y;
end;
```

In my specific case I want to pass my object pointer along with the overlapped data pointer of ReadFileEx (Windows Async I/O) so I can access the object in the callback.

Is there some equivalent function that provides similar functionality in Delphi (2006)?

Comment: Another useful thing that can make Delphi programmer envy is  `offsetof` for record or object fields.

Comment: @Serg: There are similar workarounds like LURD's and my solution for `offsetof` - not quite as convenient as the macro but they work.

Comment: @blerontin: Are you sure you got the levels of indirection right? `tOuterRecord` contains a pointer to a `tInnerRecord` and `SomeCallback` takes a `pInnerRecord` by value?

Comment: @UliGerhardt: Thanks for the hint. I have changed the `inner` field in the `tOuterRecord` declaration from `pInnerRecord` to `tInnerRecord`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm out of compiler just now, but this should do the trick:

```
Out := Pointer( Cardinal(pIn) - Cardinal(@TOuterRecord(nil^).inner));
```

---

David explains why there could be no direct equivalent function in Delphi. 
So here is a function that comes closest:

```
function ContainingRecord( var aField; aFieldOffsetRef : Pointer) : Pointer;
{$IF Declared(NativeUInt) = False}
type
  NativeUInt = Cardinal;
{$IFEND}
begin
  Result := Pointer(NativeUInt(@aField) - NativeUInt(aFieldOffsetRef));
end;
```

Calling example:

```
Out := ContainingRecord(pIn^, @pOuterRecord(nil).inner);
```

Comment: The macro is parameterised on the field name. This is not.

Comment: @LU RD, you were missing an `@` in front of the `pIn` - I made the same mistake at first :-). Otherwise your solution is fine and quite a bit shorter than mine.

Comment: If this is really the answer, then the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462103/delphi-offset-of-record-field

Comment: @David: Not really - it's about the opposite direction: `CONTAINING_RECORD` vs. `offsetof`. Which of course in this case amounts to an additional `-` sign. :-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt I'm assuming that anyone that is capable of asking this question is capable of understanding the `-` operator

Comment: @UliGerhardt, thanks for the edit. One should always have the compiler ready to confirm :-)

Comment: FTR, this question: [`"Get Position of a struct var AKA Offset of record field"`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13168959/576719) also deals with how to find an offset in a record.

Comment: @LURD, @UliGerhardt: Have updated the answer to match the changed definition of `tOuterRecord.inner` field.

Comment: @blerontin, I think my lastest update is the more natural look of `ContainingRecord` (with a reference to the `aField`). Calling changed to `Out := ContainingRecord(pIn^, ...);`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with some casts and pointer arithmetic, but not in a nicely packaged macro (as David already mentioned). Something like:

```
procedure SomeCallback(var pIn: pInnerRecord); stdcall;
const
  p = pOuterRecord(nil);
var
  Offset: Integer;
  Out: pOuterRecord;
begin
  Offset := INT_PTR(@p^.inner) - INT_PTR(p);
  Out := Pointer(INT_PTR(@pIn) - Offset);
  Out.field1 := pIn.x + pIn.y;
end;
```

and

```
var
 outer: tOuterRecord;
 inner: tInnerRecord;
begin
  inner.x := 1;
  inner.y := 2;
  outer.inner := @inner;
  SomeCallback(outer.inner);
  Assert(outer.field1 = 3);
end;
```

works. Please note that I had to add a `var` in the parameter list of `SomeCallback`.

Comment: The macro is parameterised on the field name. This is not.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure what you mean by paramterised as I have neither function nor macro. Are you saying my two-liner doesn't do what the macro "call" does?

Comment: The macro can be used with any struct member, passed in as a param

Comment: @David, I still don't get it. One can replace the `inner` in the first line of the procedure body just as well.

Comment: Then it's not a parameter. It's hard coded. You need different function for each field.

Comment: It's not a function. It's an inplace replacement for the macro **call**. The `inner` is exactly as hardcoded in my solution as it probably is in the original C code. Of course the macro "call" is more readable than my solution but at least it works.

Comment: Look at the macro in detail and note that the field is the third parameter. It is not hard coded.

Comment: OK, I guess you're telling me that the answer to "Is there some equivalent function that provides similar functionality in Delphi (2006)?" is "No" - agreed. But there is a solution to what I suppose is the OP's **real** question, i.e. "What can I do to make it work in Delphi (2006)?"

Comment: Right. I was treating it very literally. I mean, of course you can do a subtraction in Delphi. I'm just making the point that the full equivalent to that macro is not even possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You could get something equivalent provided records have RTTI. Just can't remember whether the extended RTTI in XE+ extends to records.

Comment: @MarjanVenema No, because the C macro evaluates the offset at compile time

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yeah ok, I just meant the "name being a parameter" part of it not being possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I haven't checked, but I guess Delphi also evaluates the offset at compile time.

Comment: @LURD Yes, the right hand side of the subtraction in your answer is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent in Delphi. It's not possible for there to be such a thing because Delphi does not have macros and a pre-processor.

Obviously it's possible in Delphi to work out the [offset for a specific field in a specific record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462103/delphi-offset-of-record-field#14462201). And then it's trivial to perform the subtraction required to get the containing record base address. But what you cannot do is express that calculation once and re-use it for any general field/record pair, as can be done with the C macro.

You will need to write one function for each field/record pair that you work with in this way.